# Compile Air Application in FDT5.6?

Tags: actionscript-3, air, fdt

I was download last version of fdt ,
i create air project and when i want compile and test it give me an error:

`An internal error occurred during: "Compile"`.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: If there is a full stack trace related to that Exception, post it, you may have not configured something correctly or there is something wrong with this latest version.

Comment: FDT 5.6 was released some time ago and is outdated. The new version has been working correctly for many people. It could you your Flex SDK, Flash Player Version or permissions on your file system. We really need more info to help more.

Comment: Any more info? Does the issue still exist?